# Getting XmlPullParserException for consuming SOAP service using KSOAP2 API

Tags: java, android, ksoap2

I am trying to access a SOAP service using below java code which I want to use in my Android app but getting `XmlPullParserException`.

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <{http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}SOAP-ENV:Envelope>@1:114 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4a65e0)
```

I checked all XmlPullParserException related tag no luck.
Please help me to rectify my code.

```
        import java.io.IOException;

        import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
        import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;
        import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
        import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
        import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
        import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
        import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

            public class SoapClientClass {

                private static String SOAP_ACTION = "/Process Definition";       
                private static String METHOD_NAME = "EmployeeDetailsOperation";       
                private static String NAMESPACE = "http://InputMessageNamespace";       
                private static String URL ="http://10.213.45.05:5026/EmployeeService";    

                public static void main(String[] args)
                {
                    webserviceCall();    
                }

                private static void webserviceCall() {
                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                    // Pass parameters as Key value pair to URL 
                    request.addProperty("EmployeeId", "121"); 

                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                    try {
                        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("IOException");          
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                        System.out.println("XmlPullParserException");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    SoapPrimitive result = null;
                    try {
                        result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                    } catch (SoapFault e) {
                        System.out.println("SoapFault");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //to get the data         
                    String resultData = result.toString();
                    System.out.println("Result as String: \n"+resultData);

                }
            }
```

Comment: Hi, I am running with the same issue, did you find the fix for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue, and it was related, to the SoapEnvelope Version.

In this line of code I was using VER12 when I changed it to VER11(which you re already using) it worked

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
```

Maybe you can test other versions there is three from VER10 to VER12

Answer (score 0):

Edit ur code according to the below code lines...

```
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://InputMessageNamespace/Process Definition";       
                private static String METHOD_NAME = "EmployeeDetailsOperation";       
                private static String NAMESPACE = "http://InputMessageNamespace";
```

Comment: I checked with adding the NAMESPACE with SOAP ACTION it's giving same error XmlPullParserException.

Comment: are you using .Net WebService?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the "/" at the end of URL string:

```
private static String URL ="http://10.213.45.05:5026/EmployeeService/";
```

and instead of SOAP_ACTION use NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME

Comment: I tried adding "/" at the end of URL, it's giving IOException.

Comment: I checked with adding the NAMESPACE with SOAP ACTION it's giving same error XmlPullParserException

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue, I guess this issue is because of the URL we use to connect with the website. so I solved the issue by changing my website URL like this   http://www.example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl/.

Example:

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(http://www.example.com.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl/, 900000000);
androidHttpTransport.call(" ", env);